# MQL4 Can you get the trade volume from the One Click Panel?

Tags: trading, quantitative-finance, mql4, metatrader4, mt4

Does anyone know if and how you can get the trade volume from the One Click Trade panel on the current chart?

I'm putting together some quick trade scripts and would be great to pull the current trade volume or lot size from the one click panel.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

### IMHO no

The recent 24 months of Metatrader 4 ( re-inventing ) product updates have brought a few teasing elements ( One-Click-Trading[TM] (**OCT**), or Depth-Of-Market (**DOM**), New-MQL4 (**nMQL4**) ).

The bad news, nevertheless, is that neither of these have improved the programming of the trading experience.

**OCT** has ( according to previous research ) **no API exposed into MQL4** / nMQL4 namespace

**DOM** displays, if any, just the stack of own ( local ) orders

**nMQL4** has devastated ( due to it's changed syntax/compilation rules) literally countless thousands of man*years invested in MQL4 & DLL/API-integrated code-bases

In order to present at least somehow balanced view, one must also admit a positive move in the last 24 months.

Last summer Metatrader Terminal, Build 452+, **stopped blocking** the key thread for low-intensity HFT practices and the central blocking via **TradeContextBUSY** started to remain free for further Trade Management tasks. Nevertheless a good question is, how can that be possible so long time, to remove such a brutal real-time trading system flaw as late as in 2013 ...

Comment: nice answer.  I certainly couldn't find anything related to api for the trading panel!  Interesting about the thread blocking!

Comment: @JamesLock Oh yes, sir. Thread resources and an (in)ability to control the near-real-time operations during trading is essential. One can do one's best to defer hddIO-s that also blocks to off-peak local control-loop, but the **TradeContextBUSY** was an almost un-avoid-able killer ( Well, there was a workaround possible, but at a remarkable cost, while the design-fault was suspected to be a feature, kept in favour of the Broker-side business, that pays license fees to MetaQuotes. Pretty happy that at least this dirty and obsolete issue was removed ).